# SQL smart search possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull a list from a large repository. And if there are spaces in this search, I separate the spaces and search separately. So far everything is working fine. And I am sending a list to the JS side to highlight the searched words. The word in the example search is 'paston'. I need to search for it as 'piston' or 'peston', is it possible? The only way I could think of was to change each letter of the words coming from the search in SQL to _ respectively and add them to the end with or, like '_iston' or 'p_ston' or 'pi_ton'. but I'm not sure if this works slow. Does anyone have any suggestions or know of a ready-made structure in SQL?

My SQL code is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStoklar]                
@PageIndex  nvarchar(15)
,@PageSize nvarchar(15)
,@Ara nvarchar(max)
AS
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);   
    DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100);
SET @sql = '
Select STOK_KODU,STOK_ADI,GRUP_KODU from TBLSTSABIT where 1=1'

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
 SELECT Deger FROM dbo.splitstring(''+@Ara+'')
OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
   SET @sql=@sql+' AND STOK_ADI+STOK_KODU+GRUP_KODU LIKE  ''%'+@NAME+'%'''
      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
  END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR 
SET @sql = @sql + ' order by STOK_KODU asc offset (CAST('+@PageIndex+' as int)*CAST('+@PageSize+' as int)) Rows fetch next CAST('+@PageSize+' as int) rows only
'
                  EXEC sp_executesql @sql; 
                    PRINT  @SQL;
 
    RETURN 
  END
```

on the C# side like this

```
  StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
            JsonModel jsonmodel = new JsonModel();
            if (Arama != "")
            {
                foreach (var item in Arama.Split(' '))
                {
                    test.Append(item + "~");
                }
            }
            test.Remove(test.ToString().Length - 1, 1);
            jsonmodel.Filtre = test.ToString();
            int pagesize = 15;
            var tbrow = isStatic.GetStokListesi(pageindex, pagesize, Arama);
            jsonmodel.NoMoredata = tbrow.Count < pagesize;
            jsonmodel.HTMLString = isStatic.RenderToString(PartialView("_partial", tbrow));
            return Json(jsonmodel);
```

This is the search function.

```
 public static List<Stoklar> GetStokListesi(int pageindex, int pagesize, string Arama)
        {
            using (blabla db = new blabla())
            {
                return db.Database.SqlQuery<Stoklar>("[GetStoklar] @PageIndex,@PageSize,@Ara",
                     new SqlParameter("@PageIndex", pageindex.ToString()), new SqlParameter("@PageSize", pagesize.ToString()), new SqlParameter("@Ara", Arama)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to use this more meaningfully on the SQL side?

Comment: "but I'm not sure if this works slow"  Try, and see ...

Comment: this will cause the query to be too long characters, so if there is a more efficient way, I'd like to use it.

Comment: Check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: this is ideal for close words, but there is no closeness in this. meaningless words resulting from wrong key presses, for example. or misspelled words.

Comment: It's possible but you'll need to build it yourself by using  wildcard operators and applying your own ranking mechanism and it will be very slow if there are a lot of words to search for potential matches

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all single characters in a word by an '_', and then use these results in a LIKE

For replacing all single characters in a word, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/SG50_oTj)